# pandas create a flag when merging two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two `df` - `df_a` and `df_b`,

```
# df_a
number    cur
1000      USD
2000      USD
3000      USD

# df_b
number    amount    deletion
1000      0.0       L
1000      10.0      X
1000      10.0      X
2000      20.0      X
2000      20.0      X
3000      0.0       L
3000      0.0       L
```

I want to left merge `df_a` with `df_b`,

```
df_a = df_a.merge(df_b.loc[df_b.deletion != 'L'], how='left', on='number')
df_a.fillna(value={'amount':0}, inplace=True)
```

but also create a flag called `deleted` in the result `df_a`, that has three possible values - `full`, `partial` and `none`;

`full` - if all rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion = L`;

`partial` - if some rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion = L`;

`none` - no rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion = L`;

Also when doing the merge, rows from `df_b` with `deletion = L` should not be considered; so the result looks like,

```
 number    amount    deletion    deleted    cur
 1000      10.0      X           partial    USD
 1000      10.0      X           partial    USD
 2000      20.0      X           none       USD
 2000      20.0      X           none       USD
 3000      0.0       NaN         full       USD
```

I am wondering how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is compare `deletion` column and aggregate [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) and 
[`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html), create helper `dictionary` and last `map` for new column:

```
g = df_b['deletion'].eq('L').groupby(df_b['number'])
m1 = g.any()
m2 = g.all()

d1 = dict.fromkeys(m1.index[m1 & ~m2], 'partial')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(m2.index[m2], 'full')
#join dictionries together
d = {**d1, **d2}
print (d)
{1000: 'partial', 3000: 'full'}

df = df_a.merge(df_b.loc[df_b.deletion != 'L'], how='left', on='number')
df['deleted'] = df['number'].map(d).fillna('none')
print (df)
   number  cur  amount deletion  deleted
0    1000  USD    10.0        X  partial
1    1000  USD    10.0        X  partial
2    2000  USD    20.0        X     none
3    2000  USD    20.0        X     none
4    3000  USD     NaN      NaN     full
```

For specify column `none`, if want create dictionary for it:

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys(m1.index[m1 & ~m2], 'partial')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(m2.index[m2], 'full')
d3 = dict.fromkeys(m2.index[~m1], 'none')
d = {**d1, **d2, **d3}
print (d)
{1000: 'partial', 3000: 'full', 2000: 'none'}

df = df_a.merge(df_b.loc[df_b.deletion != 'L'], how='left', on='number')
df['deleted'] = df['number'].map(d)
print (df)
   number  cur  amount deletion  deleted
0    1000  USD    10.0        X  partial
1    1000  USD    10.0        X  partial
2    2000  USD    20.0        X     none
3    2000  USD    20.0        X     none
4    3000  USD     NaN      NaN     full
```